# $\gcd(4n+1, n+2)$ is found in what sense?

Tags: divisibility

What is the gcd of these two numbers? Is it possible to find the gcd? It should be $1$ when $n=1$, but $3$ when $n=5$.

$4n+1 = (3)(n+2) + (n-5)$ <-- This step is only valid when $n \geq 5$

How do I find the gcd?

Comment: $(4n+1, n+2) = (-7, n+2) = (n+2, 7)$, so if $7 | n + 2$ then the gcd is $7$, otherwise it is $1$.

Comment: The Eulclidean algorithm works for any pair integers, not only the nonnegative ones. Thus, it is irrelevant whether $n\geqslant 5$ or not.

Comment: correction to question: when $n=5, \gcd(4n+1,n+2)=\gcd(21,7)=7$, not $3$

Comment: @PedroTamaroff: The remainder must be greater than or equal to zero.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint** $\ $ By Euclid $\,\gcd(n\!+\!2,4\color{#c00}n\!+\!1) = \gcd(n\!+\!2,\, 4(\color{#c00}{-2})\!+\!1)\,$ since $\  \color{#c00}{n\equiv -2}\pmod{\!n\!+\!2}$

---

Similarly we have  $\ \gcd(n\!-\!a,f(n)) = \gcd(n\!-\!a,f(a))\ $ for any polynomial $f(x)$ with *integer* coef's which follows by employing the following congruence rule (follow the link for a proof).

[Polynomial Congruence Rule](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/879262/242) $\ $ If $\,f(x)\,$ is *polynomial* with *integer* coefficients then  $\ A\equiv a\ \Rightarrow\ f(A)\equiv f(a)\,\pmod m.$

Note how simple the proof is when viewed this way - it amounts to simple *polynomial evaluation*.

This is a prototypical example of the power of congruence arithmetic.  It allows us to replace obscure manipulation of divisibility *relations* by simpler congruence *operations and equations*, which allows reuse of our well-honed intuition on analogous integer arithmetic. The common structure in both arithmetics is abstracted out when one goes on to study (quotient) rings.

Comment: I don't understand why you took $n \equiv 2 (\mod n+2)$

Comment: @Don By Euclid we know  $\, \gcd(a,b) = \gcd(a,b')\ $ if $\  b'\equiv b\pmod a.\ $ Above is a special case of this, because $\ {\rm mod}\ n\!+\!2\!:\,\ n\!+\!2\equiv 0\,\Rightarrow\, n\equiv -2\,\Rightarrow\, 4n\!+\!1\equiv 4(-2)+1\equiv -7\ \ $

Answer (score 4):

Since $4\cdot(n+2)+(-1)\cdot(4n+1)=7$, we can say that either $\gcd(4n+1,n+2)=1$ or $\gcd(4n+1,n+2)=7$. Both cases can happen: for $n=1$ the gcd is $1$, for $n=5$ the gcd is $7$.

Comment: Why would the gcd = 1? How?

Comment: @DonLarynx If $n=1$, then $4n+1=5$ and $n+2=3$; what's $\gcd(5,3)$?

Answer (score 1):

The gcd divides $4n +1 - 4 (n+2) = -7$, so it can only be $1$ or $7$. If $7$ divides $n+2$, then $n \equiv -2 \pmod{7}$, so $4 n + 1 \equiv -8 + 1 \equiv 0 \pmod{7}$.

Thus the gdc is $7$ when $n \equiv -2 \pmod{7}$, and $1$ otherwise.

Comment: How can it be 1?

Answer (score 1):

If integer $d$ divides both $n+2,4n+1, d$ must divide $4(n+2)-(4n+1)=7$

Clearly $7|(n+2)\iff7|(4n+1)$

Now $7|(n+2)\iff n\equiv-2\pmod7\equiv5$

Comment: Did you mean $d$ must divide $4(n + 2) - (4n + 1) = 7$?

Comment: @N.F.Taussig, Clearly so.Thanks

Comment: But what if $n = 6$?

Comment: @DonLarynx, $n=6\iff n+2=8,4n+1=25\implies(n+2,4n+1)=1$ Not sure why you are interested on a specific value of $n$